# Trouble with Firestore collection design

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a design for a comments section in my firestore database, I am just struggling with one part of it. Ive tried to make it efficient in terms of number of reads/writes to save on costs.

The plan is to make a Collection that has a single document for the item we are commenting about. Inside that i will have a sub collection of document (each document will be a block holding an array with 50 comments). The current block will number will be stored in the parent document, at the same level as the sub collection.

```
+Doc1
     -Block num : 1 
     -Subcollection
                  + 0 : Array of 50 comments  
                  + 1 : Array of 50 comments 
                   etc
```

So i wanted each comment to have certain properties, e.g. an id, comment text, username and 2 arrays of users who have liked/disliked it.

This way i can order by most recent comment (as I just read the blocks backwards.)

My problem is that I want to order by the most liked or disliked comments... as now each block could have comments with a large amount of likes.

Is there a way of structuring this, either through making a new collection or adjusting this one, whereby I would not have to read in every block to order by number of likes?

Also if anyone knows any flaw with my design in general please don't hesitate to suggest improvements.

Thank you for your help in advance :)

--- edit

Sorry guys I forgot to mention that I wanted to avoid making every comment a document as this would cost a lot of money when reading large quantities.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to use Firestore queries across all comments, each comment will have to be a separate document. Since you explicitly rules out that option, you can't rely on Firestore queries to implement the use-case.

In that case, the next option would typically be to find a data model that allows your use-case. For example, how about sharding the comments over documents based on their number of upvotes? So the top 50 most upvoted comments are in document1, the next 50 in document2, etc. That way you can get the most popular comments will be in a single (or at most a few) documents.

Note that this will lead to quite complex code for writing the votes, and potentially having to shuffle comments around the documents. This is the trade-off you will have to make: is the additional complexity and the cost of your time worth the savings that you have by needing fewer read operations?

Comment: Hi Frank, I like your idea. Do you think it would be viable to have a cloud function handle a upvote/downvote then I just read all the comment blocks/shards in and combine them into 1 large js array. Increment/decrement the comment that needs to be changed and the resort the array. Then just chop the array based on every 50 comments and set them to be the documents on firebase. I would also keep a seperate collection for newest comments (effectively duplicating data) and would switch which collection they read from based on what they select in the ui.

Comment: We're talking about code here, so likely all is possible. Whether it's feasible is something subjective. I think you'll be trading a lot of your time and code complexity for relatively small saving. But if you say the savings are not small and worth it, you'd be equally right.

Comment: Ive given it some thought i decided it will be worthwhile... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry Frank I have another question. If you have Document -> Collection -> Document and you read the sub collection document, how many reads would this be? The reference I will be using is  db.collection('parentCollection').doc(parentDoc).collection("sub collection").doc(sub collection doc);... Will this be one read as we are just getting the sub collection doc or is it 2 (both the parentdoc and subcollection doc) ?